# Update mulit rows with one SQL request

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

How I can update 10 rows with one SQL request

```
UPDATE gallery_photos SET queue=:queue WHERE id = :id AND SET queue=:queue2 WHERE id = :id2";
```

something like this

Comment: Do you want to set the whole rows with just 1 value or multiple values?

Comment: No, each row will have other value(queue)

Comment: This is very inefficent, hard to debug/trace. Why would one want to do this? Just prepare a statement and execute it multiple times inside a transaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with:

```
UPDATE gallery_photos
    SET queue = (CASE WHEN id = :id THEN :queue
                      WHEN id = :id2 THEN :queue2
                      ELSE queue  -- strictly speaking, this is not not be necessary because of the outer `WHERE`
                 END)
    WHERE id IN (:id, :id2);
```